# Least-squares training error

Tags: classification, least-squares, regularization

In classification problems, the training error typically *decreases* as further training examples are acquired. However, in my current least-squares problem, the training error actually *increases* as further observations are made. Is this the case in general? Why might this happen?

Comment: I would think this should be the case in general... harder to overfit a huge dataset.  Think of an extreme case. For example 3 observations, you will inevitably overfit.

Comment: What kind of data are your observations? Could there be a time-relevant factor in the observations that you have, for ex. that there was more noise/variance in later collected data?

Answer (score 1):

If your model is terribly misspecified then you can have that more data makes things worse as more data makes the model's lack of fit more evident. Here's an example:

```
set.seed(1)
x <- seq(0, 1000, length = 10000)
y <- sin(x) + rnorm(length(x),0, .1) ## just some terribly non-linear data
plot(y~x, main = "Y as a function of X")

nsamp <- round(seq(50, 10000, length = 500)) ## number of obs used
train.err <- numeric(length(nsamp))
for(n in 1:length(nsamp))
{
  mod <- lm(y[1:n] ~ x[1:n]) ## we're adding more obs each iteration
  train.mse[n] <- mean((mod$fitted.values - y[1:n])^2) ## training MSE
}

plot(train.mse ~ nsamp, xlab = "Number of samples", ylab = "Training MSE", main = "Training MSE as a function of n")
```

This is what the training MSE plot looks like:
[image: training MSE]

This is a pretty extreme example, though, as it should be obvious that a linear model is a horrible idea here. Nevertheless, this does show how the training MSE can increase with more data.